# Heroku deploying app and adding SSH key

Tags: node.js, heroku

Trying to push code to the Heroku server using this command

```
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: jaskobh@hotmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
Your Heroku account does not have a public ssh key uploaded.
Could not find an existing public key at ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Would you like to generate one? [Yn] Y
Generating new SSH public key.
Uploading SSH public key C:/Users/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
Authentication successful.


$ git push heroku master
```

but receive error

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad
Connection abandoned.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So key is uploaded and it exist but it wont let me push the code.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

SSH asks you to confirm the key of a server the first time you connect to it, but git gives you an error straight away. But SSH will remember that server after your first attempted connection, *even if it wasn't successful*.

Run this command on the commandline:

```
ssh heroku.com
```

And you'll see a prompt like this:

```
The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (50.19.85.132)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Type "yes". You won't connect to the remote machine - Heroku doesn't allow remote logins - but ssh will remember that host key, and you'll be able to `git push`.